# Shortest path spanning tree with 1 weighted edges vs MST

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

I currently studying about graphs and their algorithms, and i noticed a question which i don't know to to exactly prove:

If we have a connected, undirected graph G=(V,E), and **every** edge is with weight=1,is it true to say that every spanning tree that built from the shortest paths from the root, is a minimum spanning tree?

I ran some examples in http://visualgo.net/sssp.html and is seems for me that the answer for this question is true, but someone can show me how can i prove this? 
and another question that crossed my mind, does the other direction is also true?

Comment: "Does the spanning tree that return from Shortest-path-algorithm is the MST" doesn't sound a lot like a legit sentence in the english language. Could you be more clearer? Shortest path from where?

Comment: @ShreyansSheth agree, i'll edit

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every tree has exactly `n - 1` edges. Since all weights are equal to `1`, every spanning tree of `G` has a total weight of `n - 1`. It is also true for the minimal spanning tree. So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: **Not Necessarily**

Consider the triangle graph with unit weights - it has three vertices *x,y,z*, and all three edges *{x,y},{x,z},{y,z}* have unit weight. 
 The shortest path between any two vertices is the direct path. Agree?
However, to satisfy the condition of a MST in the graph, you have to put together a set of 2 edges connecting the 3 vertices. Say *{x,y}, {y,z}* for example. This does not represent the shortest path between any pair of vertices.
Hence, your proposition is false :)

Comment: You are wrong. Every spanning tree of that graph has exactly `n - 1` edges hence it's total weight is equal to `n - 1`.

Comment: The initial question was entirely different. I will delete this answer